# Two Stack Overflow accounts appearing in flair, and other strange goings-on

Tags: bug, status-completed

The other day I had 213 points on Stack Overflow, and then the next day I logged in and only had 212. I couldn't quite figure out how I might lose just one point, but I didn't dwell too much on it.

Today, however, I was on one of my other Stack Exchange sites and noticed that it had me listed on Stack Overflow as only having 1 point.  Horrified, I jumped back to Stack Overflow and noticed that I still had 212 points.

I went to my flair on a whim and noticed that it had two Stack Overflow icons in my combined profile flair, and also had doubled my StackOverflow medals and points, so that I had 1.1k and 37 bronze medals:

[image]

The listing of only 1 point on StackOverflow is not reproducible, but the flair problem is.

Has anyone experienced this before and does anyone know what is causing it?  Is my one-point loss related at all?

Comment: Also, Stack Overflow does not appear among your top 5 accounts on [your profile here on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/176880/andrew-latham).  --- Oh, wait, now it does...

Comment: Hmm. An API request for your [SO profile](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/users/1146679) shows 212 rep, but your [network profile](http://stackauth.com/1.0/users/2a7a420c-f911-49a4-bbaa-241855430c4d/associated) shows 1 rep on SO, even though it's the same ID

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you logged in a few days ago we noticed you had an old account and merged the two.  Unfortunately this happened at a time *exactly* matching when stackexchange.com was updating its user base, so it observed a very weird half-merged version of your account.

I've since run a few batches to get the right data in there and manually cleared your flair cache, your network flair should now be correct (note that only sites where you have 200+ rep are included).

Here's the live flair:

[image: profile for Andrew Latham on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

Comment: Actually it's still showing up in the live flair there as having two StackOverflow accounts, just as before

Comment: @Andrew - your browser caches the result for a few days, you'll need to hard refresh to see a new image, use `Ctrl+F5`.

Comment: It worked.  Thanks for your help!